# Problem with exporting FBX file with multiple materials and UV Maps

Tags: export

I'm trying to export FBX file to Substance Painter with multiple materials and multiple UVs merged together (merged under one name) I have vertex groups for them and materials.

When I'm trying to export selection only this Error pops up : https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYuXV.jpg

[image]

Heres link to blend file: https://mab.to/aXVEW8bPC

Thanks in advance for any anwsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to export FBX and said error was poping up. It was 3 objects with 3 different UV maps on one MAP ( i think its called UV Atlas). 3 materials all assigned even had vertex group for each one. After multiple trys i separated all of the objects and started exporting them one by one. It appears UV map on one of them wouldnt let the whole model to export. I tried with materials as i heard that un assigned materials can prevent you from exporting... i tried saving to obj and than back to fbx still nothing. I made new seams (cause i found in error info multiple UVIndex mentions) and unwrapped it once more and it exported. Simply as that.

Answer (score -2):

The problem was one of UV maps was screwing it up.

Redid it and it worked.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what the issue was and what steps you took to solve it?